# How do you find out where Lubuntu applications are after installation? (Grive specifically)

Tags: lubuntu, software-installation, grive

*I'm very, very new to Linux / Lubuntu*

I have successfully installed several programs and found them in obvious locations. That said, I'm trying to install Grive, and since I'm using Lubuntu, I don't have the Ubuntu search feature to find Grive Setup that the installation instructions refer to. I cannot seem to locate the appropriate setup file to move forward. I'd love some help with this specific issue and also general comments on how to identify where installed programs go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install Grive do this in a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thefanclub/grive-tools
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grive
```

After that, go to the folder you want to sync (for example):

```
mkdir ~/Documents/GoogleDrive
cd ~/Documents/GoogleDrive
```

Run Grive and authenticate:

```
grive -a
```

It will open a web browser page and after you accept you'll see a code. Right click and copy. Then right click in terminal and select `Paste`

Now, everytime you want to sync files do in a terminal:

```
cd ~/Documents/GoogleDrive
grive
```

To find out where apps get installed, this may help [File location on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455367/file-location-on-ubuntu-14-04/455382#455382)

Answer (score 0):

- Use Synaptic → Select installed package (`grive`), right click → Installed files
- or `dpkg -L grive` to list all files installed by `grive` package

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, only applications that have .desktop files are shown in the menu.
You can take a look with the file manager at /usr/share/applications.

Other applications can be run in a terminal.

Most of the time I rely on the autocomplete feature of the terminal, guess the first two letters of the command/application and press [tab]